# Remove a property of a multidimensional array tree - using lodash or underscore or js

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

Example tree:

```
[
    { id: 32, name: 'unique name', children: [] },
    { id: 43, name: 'unique name', children: [] },
    { id: 55, name: 'unique name', children: [
        { id: 31, name: 'unique name', children: [] },
        { id: 63, name: 'unique name', children: [] },
        { id: 84, name: 'unique name', children: [
            { id: 47, name: 'unique name', children: [] },
            { id: 56, name: 'unique name', children: [] }
        ] }
    ] }
    { id: 67, name: 'unique name', children: [
        { id: 78, name: 'unique name', children: [] },
        { id: 89, name: 'unique name', children: [] },
    ] },
    { id: 30, name: 'unique name', children: [] }
]
```

Someone, please let me know how to remove just name property for the tree using lodash or pure js?

the output should be:

```
{ id: 32,  children: [] },
{ id: 43,  children: [] },
{ id: 55,  children: [
{ id: 31,  children: [] },
{ id: 63,  children: [] },
{ id: 84,  children: [
{ id: 47,  children: [] },
{ id: 56,  children: [] }] }
] }
{ id: 67,  children: [
{ id: 78,  children: [] },
{ id: 89,  children: [] },
] },
{ id: 30,  children: [] }
```

Comment: Use the `delete` operator. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Comment: please add what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with simple recursion and `forEach`:

```
function removeName(node) {
  delete node['name'];
  node.children.forEach(removeName);
}
```

The idea is to start with deleting `name` at the top level, and then recursively doing it again for each node in the `children` array:

```js
var tree = [{
    id: 32,
    name: 'unique name',
    children: []
  },
  {
    id: 43,
    name: 'unique name',
    children: []
  },
  {
    id: 55,
    name: 'unique name',
    children: [{
        id: 31,
        name: 'unique name',
        children: []
      },
      {
        id: 63,
        name: 'unique name',
        children: []
      },
      {
        id: 84,
        name: 'unique name',
        children: [{
            id: 47,
            name: 'unique name',
            children: []
          },
          {
            id: 56,
            name: 'unique name',
            children: []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 67,
    name: 'unique name',
    children: [{
        id: 78,
        name: 'unique name',
        children: []
      },
      {
        id: 89,
        name: 'unique name',
        children: []
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 30,
    name: 'unique name',
    children: []
  }
];


function removeName(node) {
  delete node['name'];
  node.children.forEach(removeName);
}

tree.forEach(removeName);
console.log(tree);
```

Comment: You can pass `removeName` into `forEach` instead of wrapping with anonymous function (e.g. `tree.forEach(removeName)`)

Comment: Thank you @slider

Comment: @chazsolo good point; updated.

Answer (score 2):

Just pick properties which you want. You can use `map` function:

```
let originArray = [
    { id: 32, name: 'unique name', children: [] },
    { id: 43, name: 'unique name', children: [] },
    {
        id: 55, name: 'unique name', children: [
            { id: 31, name: 'unique name', children: [] },
            { id: 63, name: 'unique name', children: [] },
            {
                id: 84, name: 'unique name', children: [
                    { id: 47, name: 'unique name', children: [] },
                    { id: 56, name: 'unique name', children: [] }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 67, name: 'unique name', children: [
            { id: 78, name: 'unique name', children: [] },
            { id: 89, name: 'unique name', children: [] },
        ]
    },
    { id: 30, name: 'unique name', children: [] }
]

let flattenArray = originArray.map(item => {
    return {
        id: item.id,
        children: item.children
    };
});

console.log(flattenArray);
```